# scrollpageposition issue on browserbackbutton press

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

For reference go to [jaipurrugs dot com](http://www.jaipurrugs.com/), Here i have a rug dot aspx page, here if you scroll down to 4-5 pages and then click on any product then i go to showdescription dot aspx and now if i press browser back button it loads back at the top instead of where the product you selected was.

You can check by view source, where you can find how i perform pagingnation by scrolling.  Want like flipkart dot com, this maintain state if come back by browser back button press.

Comment: in which browser you checked this thing,in chrome it works.

Comment: It not not working in any browser other than Firefox.